# One page two html table get specific tabels column sum

Tags: javascript, html-table

I have two tables in one page.

The first table: `table id="yeni"`

The second table: `table id="eski"`

I wrote a function to sum the specific columns of the specific table.

The only difference in the columns are the IDS. For example:

First row  1_1, 1_2, 1_3

Second row 2_1, 2_2, 2_3

```
 function sum(columno,table_id){

    var cost=0;
    var rowcount=5
    for (i=1 ; i<rowcount;i++){ 

             var t =document.getElementById( i + "_" + columno);

    cost=cost+t.value;
    }

return cost;

}
```

How do I use the parameter of the table's ID in a function to identify the table?

My HTML Table:

```
<table id="yeni" style="border: 1px solid rgb(0, 0, 0);">
   <tr id="1">
      <td><input id="1_1" style="width: 70px; font-size: 11px;"></td>
      <td><input id="1_2" style="width: 80px; font-size: 11px;"></td>
      <td><input id="1_3" style="width: 80px; font-size: 11px;"></td>
      <td><input id="1_4" style="width: 80px; font-size: 11px;"></td>
      <td><input id="1_5" style="width: 80px; font-size: 11px;"></td>
      <td><input id="1_6" style="width: 80px; font-size: 11px;"></td>
      <td><input id="1_7" style="width: 80px; font-size: 11px;"></td>
      <td><input id="1_8" type="hidden" value="75" style="width: 80px; font-size: 11px;"></td>
      <td><button></button></td>
   </tr>
   <tr id="2">
      <td><input id="2_1" style="width: 70px; font-size: 11px;"></td>
      <td><input id="2_2" style="width: 80px; font-size: 11px;"></td>
      <td><input id="2_3" style="width: 80px; font-size: 11px;"></td>
      <td><input id="2_4" style="width: 80px; font-size: 11px;"></td>
      <td><input id="2_5" style="width: 80px; font-size: 11px;"></td>
      <td><input id="2_6" style="width: 80px; font-size: 11px;"></td>
      <td><input id="2_7" style="width: 80px; font-size: 11px;"></td>
      <td><input id="2_8" type="hidden" value="30.68" style="width: 80px; font-size: 11px;"></td>
      <td><button></button></td>
   </tr>
   <tr id="3">
      <td><input id="3_1" style="width: 70px; font-size: 11px;"></td>
      <td><input id="3_2" style="width: 80px; font-size: 11px;"></td>
      <td><input id="3_3" style="width: 80px; font-size: 11px;"></td>
      <td><input id="3_4" style="width: 80px; font-size: 11px;"></td>
      <td><input id="3_5" style="width: 80px; font-size: 11px;"></td>
      <td><input id="3_6" style="width: 80px; font-size: 11px;"></td>
      <td><input id="3_7" style="width: 80px; font-size: 11px;"></td>
      <td><input id="3_8" type="hidden" value="16.56" style="width: 80px; font-size: 11px;"></td>
      <td><button></button></td>
   </tr>
   <tr id="4">
      <td><input id="4_1" style="width: 70px; font-size: 11px;"></td>
      <td><input id="4_2" style="width: 80px; font-size: 11px;"></td>
      <td><input id="4_3" style="width: 80px; font-size: 11px;"></td>
      <td><input id="4_4" style="width: 80px; font-size: 11px;"></td>
      <td><input id="4_5" style="width: 80px; font-size: 11px;"></td>
      <td><input id="4_6" style="width: 80px; font-size: 11px;"></td>
      <td><input id="4_7" style="width: 80px; font-size: 11px;"></td>
      <td><input id="4_8" type="hidden" value="30.68" style="width: 80px; font-size: 11px;"></td>
      <td><button></button></td>
   </tr>
   <tr id="5">
      <td><input id="5_1" style="width: 70px; font-size: 11px;"></td>
      <td><input id="5_2" style="width: 80px; font-size: 11px;"></td>
      <td><input id="5_3" style="width: 80px; font-size: 11px;"></td>
      <td><input id="5_4" style="width: 80px; font-size: 11px;"></td>
      <td><input id="5_5" style="width: 80px; font-size: 11px;"></td>
      <td><input id="5_6" style="width: 80px; font-size: 11px;"></td>
      <td><input id="5_7" style="width: 80px; font-size: 11px;"></td>
      <td><input id="5_8" type="hidden" style="width: 80px; font-size: 11px;"></td>
      <td><button></button></td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: will you show us some html? Just a sample from both tables please

Comment: `sum(2,'yeni');` and than in your `sum()` function find all `td`s for a `table_id` like so `$('#'+table_id).find('#'+i + "_" + columno)` and dont use not unique ids, its better to use something like `<td data-id="4_1">`

Comment: i understant that there is no pure javascript solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> for two table's cell id has rule like for first row 1_1,1_2,1_3 for
>   second row 2_1,2_2,2_3 and so on

This is a problem, the `id` attribute of any element must be unique for the entire webpage. Just because your tables have different `id` values, does not mean it helps distinguishes the cell rows.

You need to either prefix each table cell with the tables `id` value (e.g. `<td><input id="eski_4_4" style="width: 80px; font-size: 11px;"></td>`), or find your table cells differently (e.g. use the fact that they are children of your table with javascript).

Answer (score 0):

this may help you

```
sum(columno,table_id){

var cost=0;
var rowcount=5
for (i=1 ; i<rowcount;i++){ 
       var t = $(table_id).find("#" + i + "_" + columno);
       cost=cost+t.value;
}
```

return cost;
}

Comment: can you give pure javascript